# Ввод данных vk api python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог ввести свой никнейм и бот его упоминал, как он ввел свой ник. Я посмотрел документацию и ничего не нашёл. Это вообще можно реализовать?

Comment: Конкретнее можно? Где упоминал, какой никнейм?

Comment: К примеру пользователь введет ник "Tasher1337" и бот после этого будет его упоминать  в лс с ботом.

Comment: Значит, при регистрации юзера в боте нужно будет хендлером обрабатывать ввод ника юзера, а после  в бд записывать его id и никнейм, после чего извлекать их оттуда

Answer (score 1):

Держи
`vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : "[id516788761|Крутой чел]", 'random_id' : 0})`

1. Сделай команду /nick НИК
2. Запиши в бд ник человека и id
3. При пинге, вытаскивай id с nick из бд и используй [id|nick]

**Если помог, поставь галочку слева от моего ответа**